# Not getting number in SMS and proper number in Phone call

Tags: android

I have tried tel: and sms: in WebView. After click if i get URL containg tel: then i am opening call utility of phone. Then i am getting number followed by character 'N'.
An in sms: i am getting sms utility of phone but no number. In both URL number is present.

```
@Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        result = false;
        // for telephone
        if (url.contains("tel:")) {
            view.getContext().startActivity(
                    new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
            result = true;
        }



        // for SMS or message.
        if (url.contains("sms:")) {
            view.getContext().startActivity(
                    new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
            result = true;
        }
        Log.d(TAG, url);
        return result;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the most possible reason to this problem is that your url is incorrect. So you'd better check it in logcat. The url should be `tel:xxxxxxx` not anything else. Besides, there are several things incorrect in your code.

First，you should use `ACTION_CALL` or `ACTION_DIAL` not `ACTION_VIEW` when the url is starting with "`tel:`". Because there are no component in Phone application that has an intent filter with `ACTION_VIEW` and data schema tel.

Second, you should verify that the url is startsWith `tel:` and `sms:`, not only contains.

For example:

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    result = false;
    // for telephone
    if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {
        view.getContext().startActivity(
                new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(url)));
        result = true;
    }



    // for SMS or message.
    if (url.startsWith("sms:")) {
        view.getContext().startActivity(
                new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
        result = true;
    }
    Log.d(TAG, url);
    return result;

}
```